Gas giant's influence on its satellite's climate
I'm designing a fictional moon with the following characteristics and now I am curious to know about how its specific properties would influence its climate zones:

The moon orbits a gas giant at a distance of 2.7 AU from a 1.1 solar mass star.

The Amount of natural solar energy reaching this world's surface is 15% (compared to Earth having 100%)

The moon's Semi major axis is 900000 km

It has a regular day/night cycle of 38 hours.

The orbits of all the bodies involved are nearly circular.

Of course the satellite is tidally locked to its primary.

Edit: There is an atmosphere with 10% more surface pressure than on earth, and an increased amount of greenhouse gasses, in order to ensure earth-like air-, water- and surface-temperatures on average.

There is a stationary high-pressure area where the moon is closest to the gas giant, indicated by the red dot on the map.

I'm assuming that the constant gravitational influence of the gas giant creates a permanent high-pressure system through tidal bulging and compression, affecting both the ocean and the atmosphere of this moon, indicated by the arrows leading away from the red dot.

Also there is the possibility that this compression Zone would "push" the other climate zones towards the polar regions, promoting more temperate climates in these regions.


So my question is: How would the stationary high-pressure area affect the climate, particularly on the coastline near this ocean? Would it promote humid or dry weather?

I'm guessing that the winds in the upper atmosphere push east to west?

Yes there are East-to-West Winds, driven by the rotation and temperature gradients, and they are more prevalent at higher altitudes. In addition there are winds blowing from the high-pressure area over the ocean towards lower-pressure regions. Obviously the direction varies, depending on where you are located relative to the high pressure zone caused by the gas giant.

Does it have a Blank Spot during the day, or at least the year, when its primary blocks off all sunlight for several minutes (aka solar eclipse but by the primary)? Is that big giant hot enough to re-radiate enough heat to that planet for it to have liquid water? Does it have enough greenhouse effects for the same? Does it have enough atmospheric pressure and/or CO2 partial pressure to do greenhouse at large? Perhaps you don't have the climate on your planet, just snow and more snow all round the iceball.

Yes, there is a daily solar eclipse caused by the primary being located between the star and the moon. Depending on the season and your location, it's between a few minutes and 90 minutes long. The Gas giant does not radiate any heat, and the sunlight reflected by it does not affect the temperature on the moon's surface and in its atmosphere.
However, the climate is still not particularly cold due to a large amount of green house gasses in the moon's atmosphere. Because of this, the oceans, indicated by the light blue areas on the map I attached, are mostly liquid.

There wouldn't be a high-pressure  area.  There would be an atmospheric bulge, but it would be at the same pressure as the rest of the moon's atmosphere.

Hmm hmmm, the gas giant should be a black hole to not reflect any sunlight and not radiate heat (blackbody radiation is there for a reason). But a black hole cannot cause eclipses. And should the gas giant take at least 5 degrees (out of 180 possible) of the sky, its influence should be noticeable, especially on the night side. Even a 10% reflection of sunlight off a gas giant could cause enough light to never needing night vision.

Also, is the planet close enough to the gas giant to have a full solar eclipse on its surface as well? If yes, that could be quite a distinctive feature of your world :)

Yes the gas giant does reflect light, and it may cause the part of the moon exposed to it, to be very bright at least during some night hours. I'm not sure how much infrared light the primary could reflect to the moons surface. Any ideas?

There would not be a perpetual high-pressure system on the indicated area of this moon.  Gravitational attraction would lead to an atmospheric bulge toward the gas giant primary, but the bulge would be at the same pressure, given that repulsive forces would lead to any pressure variations equalising as they do in every other circumstance.
However, this area would be colder than the opposite side of the tidally locked moon, since the OP stated in comments that there are daily eclipses that would be centred around this area.
So, the climatic effect would not be that which the OP has modelled, but instead it would be a cool climatic zone, though less cold than the polar regions that would recceive consistently less solar radiation or heat from the gas giant.  It is also likely incorrect to say (as the OP did in comments) that the gas giant would radiate no heat.  See Can a gas giant have its own habitable zone?.  However, the heat received from the gas giant is likely lower than that of the sun.
So, with the cooler zone fixed to that location, I would expect a large, slight thermal low pressure zone to be centred there.  This would have the opposite of the effect that the OP has expected, pulling temperate zones toward this area.

Thank you for your answer. So it would be a low pressure area then, being slightly cooler than the equator on the other side of the moon? Low pressure area over an ocean would normally promote more humid, and in this specific case, slightly cooler weather on the coasts nearby?

Also, could there be made any assumptions, how this atmospheric bulge would alter air flow?

I doubt that the zone under the gas giant will be cooler than the rest of the planet; the gas giant is pretty big and might reflect enough solar radiation during the night to match or even exceed the total received by the other side. Also @Ben your atmosphere is too thin to get enough greenhouse going on your moon, your equilibrium temperature with this influx is 162K or -111C (based on Earth and your 15% figure listed in Q), there won't be enough water vapor to add to even the entire 1.10atm of CO2 to raise that by 110C.
